# CSS background image not appearing?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello my site is http://math.pixelworklab.com/

I am trying to add an active state to all the nav buttons (white color) but the home button is shaped differently. I added a more specific selector and it appears the rounded background .png is loading but still appearing as a square on the nav..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where have you declared the `background-image`? All I can see is the `background-color` and `none` for `background-image`.

[image: bg]

#### Will be updating the answer with the relevant fix, after your comments.

Comment: ok got it.. now what do i add to linne 219 make it only show when active?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom css line number 131 overlapping line number 222,

```
At line number 131
border-radius: 0;


At line number 222
border-radius: 3px;


I suggest you to add at line No. 222
border-radius: 3px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using border-radius CSS property:

e.g.

```
.homelink { border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px; /* An over the top example */ }
```

Good luck!